# How to do exact-match but ignore location with Fusejs?

Tags: reactjs, fuzzy-search, exact-match

So I have set up my Fuse.js as such:

```js
  const fuse = useMemo(() => {
    return new Fuse<Fees>(data, {
      includeMatches: true,
      keys: [{ name: "name" }],
      ignoreLocation: true,
      useExtendedSearch: true,
      threshold: isStrictSearch ? 0 : 0.6,
    });
  }, [data, isStrictSearch]);
```

so basically `isStrictSearch` is a boolean state, which is toggled on and off. When it's toggled on (`true`), then I set the threshold of Fuse.js to 0. However this does not work as perfectly as I want it to be. So for example I have these cases:

**DATA**

```js
const data = [
    {
        "name": "Surimi Maki Sticks - 1kg",
        ...
    },
    {
        "name": "No Worries Wild Berry Can",
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

### Case 1

Search query: `Maki Sticks 1kg`.
Result: `Surimi Maki Sticks - 1kg`.

This shouldn't happen because it should take `-` into account.

### Case 2

Search query: `No Worries Can`.
Result: `No Worries Wild Berry Can`.

This also shouldn't happen because it should take `Wild Berry` into account.

---

I'm not sure how to achieve this, I have tried other combinations for the Fuse.js options, but still not able to achieve the result I want.

Comment: I know you can set the `threshold` to a negative number, which means that it would only give exact matches, but I think it's too strict, in a way where it has to have the whole string be typed/queried then it gives the result.

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to use another logic than using Fuse.js to handle this issue:

```js
if (isStrictSearch) {
    const results = data.filter(function (datum) {
        return datum.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
    });
    return results;
} else {
    const results = fuse.search(query);
    return results.map((i) => i.item);
}
```